# Skybot Python IRCbot

Tags: python, bots, irc

I use the [skybot irc bot](https://github.com/rmmh/skybot), I'd like to ask how to remove the nick from bots answer, like

```
<User1> .calc 1+3
<Skybot> **User1:** 1+3=4
```

In each plugin there are imports, here is the script from the file that imports into all plugings (hook.py):

```
import inspect
import re


def _hook_add(func, add, name=''):
if not hasattr(func, '_hook'):
    func._hook = []
func._hook.append(add)

if not hasattr(func, '_filename'):
    func._filename = func.func_code.co_filename

if not hasattr(func, '_args'):
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
    if name:
        n_args = len(argspec.args)
        if argspec.defaults:
            n_args -= len(argspec.defaults)
        if argspec.keywords:
            n_args -= 1
        if argspec.varargs:
            n_args -= 1
        if n_args != 1:
            err = '%ss must take 1 non-keyword argument (%s)' % (name,
                        func.__name__)
            raise ValueError(err)

    args = []
    if argspec.defaults:
        end = bool(argspec.keywords) + bool(argspec.varargs)
        args.extend(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):
                    end if end else None])
    if argspec.keywords:
        args.append(0)  # means kwargs present
    func._args = args

if not hasattr(func, '_thread'):  # does function run in its own thread?
    func._thread = False


def sieve(func):
    if func.func_code.co_argcount != 5:
        raise ValueError(
                'sieves must take 5 arguments: (bot, input, func, type, args)')
    _hook_add(func, ['sieve', (func,)])
    return func

def command(arg=None, **kwargs):
    args = {}

def command_wrapper(func):
    args.setdefault('name', func.func_name)
    _hook_add(func, ['command', (func, args)], 'command')
    return func

if kwargs or not inspect.isfunction(arg):
    if arg is not None:
        args['name'] = arg
    args.update(kwargs)
    return command_wrapper
else:
    return command_wrapper(arg)


def event(arg=None, **kwargs):
    args = kwargs

def event_wrapper(func):
    args['name'] = func.func_name
    args.setdefault('events', ['*'])
    _hook_add(func, ['event', (func, args)], 'event')
    return func

if inspect.isfunction(arg):
    return event_wrapper(arg, kwargs)
else:
    if arg is not None:
        args['events'] = arg.split()
    return event_wrapper


def singlethread(func):
    func._thread = True
    return func


def regex(regex, flags=0, **kwargs):
    args = kwargs

def regex_wrapper(func):
    args['name'] = func.func_name
    args['regex'] = regex
    args['re'] = re.compile(regex, flags)
    _hook_add(func, ['regex', (func, args)], 'regex')
    return func

if inspect.isfunction(regex):
    raise ValueError("regex decorators require a regex to match against")
else:
    return regex_wrapper
```

I'll be very thankful to anyone who responds ;)

Comment: Your indentation is a mess, could you clean that up please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the nickname from the answer try using `say()` instead of a normal `return` at the end of the plugin function. Bitcoin plugin uses that:

```
from util import http, hook

@hook.command(autohelp=False)
def bitcoin(inp, say=None):
    ".bitcoin -- gets current exchange rate for bitcoins from mtgox"
    data = http.get_json("https://mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php")
    ticker = data['ticker']
    say("Current: \x0307$%(buy).2f\x0f - High: \x0307$%(high).2f\x0f"
        " - Low: \x0307$%(low).2f\x0f - Volume: %(vol)s" % ticker)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I didn't notice about this plugin just because I deleted it. Really, thank you!